# C++ Windows - Programatically check if a software access internet?

Tags: c++, windows, networking

Assume I use C++ on Windows 8.1 and I have the id of the window/process of the software. Can I check if this software connect to the internet? The purpose is checking if the software may do something suspicious or not.

Comment: You do know that e.g. UDP is connection*less*? There are also other ways to do nefarious things over a network without having a "connection". With high enough privileges you can probably get a list of open sockets of a process, and get their type, and for TCP even get where they are connected, but to figure out if there's something "bad" happening with only that information might not be trivial.

Comment: seem like this question is not welcoming, please give me the reason. I'm total new at this field.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Thanks for your comment, so you mean it's not possible to check a software access internet? (about the check suspicious, I'll combine other method)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks, I mean for windows, sorry I forgot put that.

Comment: Check out programs like, e.g., [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). How to program this yourself is a too broad question.

Comment: thanks for your recommendation, @chtz :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GetTcpTable2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408406.aspx) (IPv4), [`GetTcp6Table2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408405.aspx) (IPv6), or [`GetExtendedTcpTable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365928.aspx) (both IPv4 and IPv6) to enumerate active TCP sockets, and get their owning process IDs.

You can use [`GetExtendedUdpTable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365930.aspx) to enumerate active UDP sockets, and get their owning process IDs.